# Social login with different activity

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, google-signin

I want to integrate different social logins in my app , like Google Plus, Facebook, etc. But I haven't found out how to do this in different classes. 
I would like to have it like this:

1. MainActivity - activity where placed some content. If user is not authorized, then will starting LoginActivity.
2. LoginActivity has two authorization buttons: Google Plus and Facebook. But I want place the logic of authorization in different classes for Google Plus and Facebook separately.
3. Sign out. I want place sign out button in MainActivity.

Please, tell me where I can find some examples for this or how I can do this.

Comment: *`Please, tell me where I can find some examples for this or how I can do this`* Google it my friend

Comment: If I found, then I would not ask here

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ (for Facebook integration)

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating(Google Integration )

Follow these two for social login integration.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but how I can combine this two login integration in my app? I would like have two authorization buttons: Google Plus and Facebook. And I want place the logic of authorization in different classes for Google Plus and Facebook separately.

Comment: kindly find this solution 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168709/8713823

Answer (score 0):

Use this class for example

```
public class GoogleAuthClient {

private static final String TAG = "GoogleSignInActivity";

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private Activity activity;
private Fragment fragment;
private String clientId;


private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


private com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
private GoogleSignInResultCallback googleSignInResultCallback;


public GoogleAuthClient(Activity activity, Fragment fragment, String clientId) {
    this(activity, clientId);
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

public GoogleAuthClient(Activity activity, String clientId) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.clientId = clientId;

}

protected void init(GoogleSignInResultCallback googleSignInResultCallback) {
    this.googleSignInResultCallback = googleSignInResultCallback;

    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(clientId)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, gso);
   
    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    signIn();
}

public void checkUser() {

    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    googleSignInResultCallback.updateUi(currentUser);
}

// call this from inside activity onActivityResult 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        googleSignInResultCallback.updateUi(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        googleSignInResultCallback.updateUi(null);

                    }
                }
            });
}

public void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    if (fragment == null) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    } else {
        fragment.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
}


public interface GoogleSignInResultCallback {
    void updateUi(FirebaseUser user);
}}
```

and usage to this class from your activity like this :

```
private void initGoogleAuth() {
    googleAuthClient = new GoogleAuthClient(this, getString(R.string.default_web_client_id));

    binding.lytGoogle.setOnClickListener(view -> {
       
        googleAuthClient.init(user -> {
            if (user != null) {

                String id = user.getUid();
                String name = user.getDisplayName();
                String email = user.getEmail();
                String photo = String.valueOf(user.getPhotoUrl());

                binding.etName.setText(name);
                binding.etEmail.setText(email);

                doSocialRegister(id, Constants.SOCIAL_GOOGLE, name, email);

            }
        });


    });


}
```

Now you Separated the Logic of google Auth in a different class and just get the data from social auth in your activity, you can create another social auth class with this way .